# Do we ever see mixing of B and V word-initially?

Tags: orthography, vulgar-latin, inscription, late-latin

In later Latin, `/b/` between vowels merged with `/w/`, eventually leading to forms like modern Italian *avere* from Latin *habēre*. This only happened within a word: *illa bucca* became Italian *la bocca*, not **la vocca*.

When these sorts of sound changes are in progress, though, they tend to ignore boundaries. For example, in modern Castilian Spanish, `/b/` becomes `[v]` between vowels, and they will indeed say `[b]`*oca* but *la* `[v]`*oca*. It's usually only once the actual *phonemes* change that word boundaries are respected: in Judeo-Spanish, this change became phonemicized and thus no longer applies in cases like *la boka*.

So, do we ever see any evidence of B and V being confused word-initially, when the previous word ends in a vowel? For example, do we ever see *la via* spelled with a B or *la bucca* spelled with a V, before this change had become fully phonemic?

Comment: There are a few relevant examples from the Appendix Probi, though they don't have full context, e.g. "baculus non uaclus," "uapulo non baplo."

Answer (score 8):

There are Latin inscriptions that show confusion between initial B and V. This is not limited to cases where the preceding word ends in a vowel, actually.

One notable example that I remember reading about appears to show assimilation of *ad v-* to [abb] in *ad voce*:

> NON // DICE // REIL // LESE // CRITA // A<sup>B</sup>BOCE

([Commodilla catacomb inscription](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commodilla_catacomb_inscription))

This is supposed to date to around the 6th century.

In Romance, a merger of word-initial B and V is found in Spanish (as is pretty well known) and also in many central and southern Italian varieties.

> Spanish, Catalan, Occitan (including Gascon), Southern Italian dialects and Sardinian neutralized the contrast between Latin <v> and <b> word-initially. [...] In Central and Southern Italian dialects, the initial position hosts either [v] (but also [β] see below) or [bː] depending on the phonological environment.

(Russo and Ulfsbjorninn; pages 5-6; the inscription cited above is then discussed as an example.)

(Note: it appears that [some varieties of Catalan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_phonology#Fricatives) actually do distinguish /b/ from /v/, but most don't.)

Other examples of word-initial B spellings for V, such as "BIXIT" for "vixit" and "BALERIAE" for "Valeriae", are mentioned by Adamik 2017.

### Works cited

- Russo, Michela and Shanti Ulfsbjorninn. 2020. Initial lenition and strength alternations (v/b) in Neapolitan: A laryngeal Branchingness condition. *Glossa: a journal of general linguistics* 5(1): 11. 1–27. DOI: https://doi.org/10.5334/gjgl.534
- Béla Adamik, "On the Vulgar Latin merger of /b/ and /w/ and its correlation with the loss of intervocalic /w/: Dialectological evidence from inscriptions", *Pallas* 103 | 2017, 25-36. Published online 30 May 2018. DOI : https://doi.org/10.4000/pallas.4030

Comment: Now I wonder if the shift from ουαλεριος to βαλεριος in Greek transliteration is recording a Greek phenomenon or a Latin one.

Comment: @cmw Probably a Greek phenomenon according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Betacism#Greek